# Using placeholders in MySQL 'COOPERATIVE' LOCK queries

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have used the so-called cooperative LOCK successfully in MySQL in the past. I had custom functions in my PHP code that ACQUIRE LOCK, RELEASE LOCK and CHECK whether lock is in effect. For example, to lock, I did something like :

```
//code
"SELECT GET_LOCK( 'unique_string', -1 ) AS acquired"
// code
return ( $row['acquired'] == 1);
```

And to unlock, I did something like:

```
// code
"SELECT RELEASE_LOCK( 'unique_string' ) AS released"
// code
return ( $row['released'] == 1 );
```

And lastly, to check if lock is in effect, I did:

```
//code
"SELECT IS_USED_LOCK( 'unique_string' ) AS connection_id"
//code
return ( NULL != $row['connection_id'] );
```

In all these cases, I used `PDO::query()` method ( i.e. no prepared statement) since my SELECT statements do not contain any parameters

Now, there is a need to concatenate input from the user to `unique_string`. Is there a way to make the `unique_string` contain a placeholder so as to use `PDO::prepare()` and avoid possible SQL injection attack?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's a regular SELECT query ant here is no reason for a placeholder not to work in

Comment: @YourCommonSense, are you suggesting that injection attack cannot work in such case? For example, if I concatenate a variable to `unique_string` like `unique_string.$variable`. What if $variable contains `;DROP *.* --`? I do not know for sure, I just want to be on the safe side.

Comment: I am suggesting that **placeholders work in SELECT queries.** and have no idea where did you get anything else

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Oh my bad! I did not see the 'NOT' in your comment. My apologies.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I have honestly looked at the question you linked to. I do not think this is a duplicate. Please take another look very closely and kindly reopen this qustion.

Comment: In a way - yes. You just invented a non-existent problem out of nowhere, so technically your question is rather off topic than duplicate. but given it boils down to "how to add a string literal to a  SELECT query though a placeholder", the duplicate suits as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue at all in using a prepared statement, just use

```
$statement = PDO::prepare("SELECT GET_LOCK( ?, -1 ) AS acquired");
$statement->execute([$uniqueString]);
```

You can also used named params, would recommend looking into PDO's prepared statements docs.

Comment: I was thinking that way too. I will implement your recommendation and accept your answer as necessary.

Comment: The placeholder must be unquoted, and the parameter must be passed as an array to `execute`, as already commented.

Comment: @deceze, please take a look at the syntax of the lock, the string is quoted, so why unquote the placeholder? Just want to know. Unfortunately, stackoverflow is a community where almost any sincere question is viewed as a challenge. Well, you may not be like that,  but I am frustrated!

Comment: @Stephen Because that's how placeholders work: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. It doesn't work like search-and-replace in strings. The database understands *on a syntactical level* that `?` is a placeholder. `'?'` is a string with a question mark in it, `?` is a placeholder.

Comment: @deceze, Got that. Could one however use a named placeholder in this case, when GET_LOCK() requires param 1 to be a string? Notice how  the reason for my question is playing out

Comment: @Stephen Nope, not seeing what's playing out here. If you pass a string as the value for that placeholder, then it'll be a string. `SELECT ?` + `execute(['foo'])` → equivalent to `SELECT 'foo'`. Whether you use *named* placeholders or *positional* placeholders (`?`) is irrelevant.